# WPF Custom Window Border for Children

Tags: wpf

I'm searching for a way to create a border of sunflowers instead of the classic rectangler border.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

To give a better understanding what a mean I created a simple thing in paint to demonstrate.

http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/174/90265955.jpg

Thanks!

-Greetz-
Vincent

Comment: Wow, if you ever get that thing going I hope to see the end result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358516.aspx